# Substring in a string

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to pick a substring from a string.

Example: I want to pick the table no from the below string starting from "T".

> Changes in table T682 (SAP TABLE)

The position of the start of the table no is same ie 17th position, but the characters in a table name are not constant. So I basically want a substring that picks from the 17th position till it finds a space. I am using the below code but it doesn't seem to work.

```
Position = InStr(1, A, " ")
TableNo = Mid(A, 17, Position)
```

Comment: Does it always have the open bracket after the space?

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook yes it does

Comment: I was going to say you could use INSTR on the bracket, but first space after character 18 will work just as well.

Answer (score 2):

Here is what you need to do:

```
Dim A As String
Dim StartPosition As Integer
Dim EndPosition As Integer

A = "Changes in table T682 (SAP TABLE)"
StartPosition = InStr(1, A, "T")
EndPosition = InStr(StartPosition, A, " ")
tableno = Mid(A, StartPosition, EndPosition - StartPosition)
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two mistakes in your code:
1. The first parameter of instr should be 18. You want to find the first space after the starting point
2. The last parameter of mid is the number of characters

So your code should look something like this:

```
Position = InStr(18, a, " ")
TableNo = Mid(a, 18, Position - 18)
```

Comment: I am getting an error saying "Invalid procedure call or argument" .

Comment: That happens if you try to do something invalid like getting a negative amount of characters. Have a look at the values in each step of your code. I'm guessing here, but I think you need to learn about the debug possibilities in VBE

Answer (score 0):

The space before T682 is character 17, the table start at character 18 so we just need to find the space after that.

The GetTable function can also be used as a worksheet function, e.g. in cell B1 enter `=GetTable(A1)` to return T682.

```
Sub Test()

    Debug.Print GetTable("Changes in table T682 (SAP TABLE)")

End Sub

Public Function GetTable(Target As Range) As String

    GetTable = Mid(Target, 18, InStr(18, Target, " ") - 18)

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way

```
s = "Changes in table T682 (SAP TABLE)"
Debug.Print Trim(Split(Split(s, "(")(0), "T")(1))
```

I am assuming the following. The format of the string will be constant i.e

1. There will be no other Capital `T` before `(`
2. There will be only 1 `(`
3. The number `T*` will be before the `(`